# Dynamically adding series to an MSCHART area

Tags: c#, addition, dynamic, mschart, series

I need to dynamically add series to an MSCHART ChartArea.
I retrieve column names from a datatable.
The series name needs to be the column name.
I can build the SERIES ADD in a string, but then what?

```
Series Trigger_Level = chart1.Series.Add("Trigger Level");
```

Developing in C#

Answer (score 0):

A series can be dynamically added with the following code:

```
chart1.Series["Trigger Level"].ChartArea = "ChartArea1";

chart1.Series.Points.Add(myPoint1);

chart1.Series.Points.Add(myPoint2);

chart1.Series.Points.Add(myPoint3);

chart1.Series.Points.Add(myPoint4);
```